# an not install service pack1 for language pack (kb2880554 ) SharePoint server 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-administration

I've SharePoint 2013 farm with service pack 1 installed for SharePoint kb2880552  and can not install service pack1 for  language pack it gives Error expected version of this product was not found in the system

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, try to execute the installation on PowerShell window with PACKAGE.BYPASS.DETECTION.CHECK=1

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0be2b28b-e430-4c34-9417-c19e6e58df4c/the-expected-version-of-the-product-was-not-found-on-the-system-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointadmin

https://www.afahru.com/2018/12/message-expected-version-of-product-was.html